# Numpad for Electron application built in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, pug, electron

I am looking for a numpad similar to http://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-numpad.html
I am new to this technology and can't understand how to use it in electron application built in Express and Pug.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this npm package [virtual keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtual-keyboard) for number pad ,etc.

Comment: I am getting this error. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getkeyboard is not a function

Comment: You need JQuery library for it.

Comment: I have added jquery library as well as keyboard libraries..
Followed this link https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/setup

Comment: It works now.. I didn't add this line : 
**require("virtual-keyboard");**

Comment: Thanks for your help.. :)